# How does bind know when to cast to pointer?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I found an interesting thing in C++.

```
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string name;

    bool check() {
        return name == "carol";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p = { "Mark" };
    list<Person> l;
    l.push_back(p);

    if (find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), bind(&Person::check, std::placeholders::_1)) == l.end())
    {
        cout << "Not found";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The if statement above works as it should. While dereferencing iterator for_each gets and object and passes it to the function. Somehow bind knows that (while biniding) the first argument of pointer-to-member-function should be a pointer. But in the following example it doesn't know that and throws an error due to casting from Person to Person*. How does bind work then? And how to pass a pointer in the following example?

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), bind(mem_fun(&Person::check), std::placeholders::_1)) == l.end()
```

I have come up with something like this but I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it.

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), bind([](Person& p) { return p.check(); }, std::placeholders::_1)) == l.end()
```

Comment: If you may use lambda, use it directly: `find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [](Person& p) { return p.check(); })`

Comment: That's cool. Yeah, much simpler. Thanks @Jarod42

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're seeing has nothing to do with `bind`, it's [`mem_fun`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) (which is deprecated, and will be removed in the next version of C++) fault. When you wrap a pointer to member function with `mem_fun`, you're required pass a **pointer** to the instance you want to invoke the member function on.

`find_if` will dereference the iterator and pass the result to its predicate, which means you're trying to pass a `Person&` instead of `Person*` to `mem_fun_t`. If you want to pass a reference, then use [`mem_fun_ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun_ref) instead. So the following will compile

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), bind(mem_fun_ref(&Person::check), std::placeholders::_1))
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As Barry [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561434/241631), you don't even need `bind` in the expression, the following works too

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Person::check))
```

Or use `mem_fun`/`mem_fun_ref`'s C++11 replacement, [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), mem_fn(&Person::check))
```

Finally, a lambda expression can also be used

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [](Person& p) { return p.check(); })
```

Comment: He can also directly use a lambda.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sure, updated. But this is one of those rare cases when a lambda is more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

The reason [`mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) does *not* work is that it:

> Creates a member function wrapper object, deducing the target type from the template arguments. The wrapper object **expects a pointer to an object** of type `T` as the first parameter to its `operator()`.

To accomplish the same thing, you need to use [`std::mem_fun_ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun_ref) (no `bind` necessary):

```
find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&Person::check))
```

But really, you should prefer the more general [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) which allows for both, and additionally the former two will become deprecated in C++17:

> Function template std::mem_fn generates wrapper objects for pointers to members, which can store, copy, and invoke a pointer to member. **Both references and pointers (including smart pointers) to an object can be used** when invoking a `std::mem_fn`.

[`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) similarly allows for both references or pointers:

> As described in Callable, when invoking a pointer to non-static member function or pointer to non-static data member, the first argument has to be a **reference or pointer** (including, possibly, smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`) to an object whose member will be accessed.

Comment: Thank you, I have completly forgotten about mem_fun_ref. And I haven't heard of mem_fn. That's fantastic! Thank you @Barry!

Comment: He can also directly use a lambda.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes he could, in this case `mem_fn` is less verbose though.

Comment: `mem_fun` etc. were deprecated in C++*11* and will be completely gone in C++17.